# [Error]: Failed to run command with error: Error Domain=Parse Code=428

Tags: parse-platform

I get this error sometimes when trying to save things to Parse or to fetch data from it.

This is not constant and appear once in a while making the operation to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted Parse for that. Here is their answer:

> Starting on 4/28/2016, apps that have not migrated their database may see a "428" error code if the request cannot be handled by the remaining shared pool of resources. If you see this error in your logs, we highly recommend migrating the database for your app without delay.

Means this happens because of starting this date all apps are on low priority but those who started DB migration. So, Migration of the DB should resolve that.